# Luhn Algorithm in C

Tags: c, luhn

I'm very new to coding and one of the assignment is to program Luhn's Algorithm. After searching on the internet, everyone's solution looks so different and foreign :( so I don't know where the problem is with my solution. Any help is appreciated!

```
int main(void)
{
    // get card number from user
    long number;
    do
    {
        number = get_long("Number: ");
    } while (number < 0);

    // isolate digits of card number
    int digit;
    int product;
    int sum;
    int totalSum;
    int counter;
    for (counter = 1; number > 9; counter++) {
        for (int i = 1; number > 9; i = i * -1) {
            digit = number % 10;

            // isolate digits that need to be multiplied by 2
            if (i == 1) {
                product = digit * 2;

                // add products' digits
                if (product > 9) {
                    sum = (product % 10) + 1;
                }
            }
            // add sum of digits that weren't multiplied by 2
            totalSum = product + sum + digit;

            // update "new" number
            number = (number - digit) / 10;
        }
    }

    // checksum
    int check = totalSum % 10;
    if (check != 0) {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    } else {
        printf("VALID\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: use this opportunity to learn using the debugger.

Comment: maybe a simple oversight: you have a condition for number in both for loops, while counter increments unbounded.

Comment: Lookup the algorithm on Wikipedia, then validate the code against that.

Comment: If everyone's solution looks so foreign, break it down until you understand it. SO is a site that provides neither tutorials nor basic debugging

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of errors in your code, most having to do with how you use variables.

1. You use `totalSum` without ever initializing it, which means it can start with any random value!
2. You add both `product` and `sum` to `totalSum` every time, but you only update their values when some condition applies.
   This means at least half the time (maybe more) you add old values you already added previously.
3. Your loops exit when `number` is 9 or less, meaning you never check the leftmost (highest) digit of number.

As the comments suggested, you should read the [pseudo code in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm#Pseudocode_implementation), look carefully what they put in each variable, and what they sum and multiply.